# Why doesn't fork() give the correct pid right away?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

When I run

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $pid;
if ($pid = fork) {
    system("sleep 100");
}
print "pid $pid\n";
```

then I get

```
pid 0
```

and when it exits

```
pid 17613
```

While it is running I can see the child process ID's

```
jasl     17612 17036  0 14:05 pts/2    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
jasl     17613 17612  0 14:05 pts/2    00:00:00 [fork.pl] <defunct>
jasl     17614 17612  0 14:05 pts/2    00:00:00 sleep 100
```

**Question**

Why do I get `pid 0` (fork success) first and then when it exits the correct `pid 17613`? It is as if the `print` line is executed twice?

Is there a way to get the PID of the sleep command from within the perl script?

Comment: `unless ($pid = fork)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as as if the print line is executed twice?

I recommend you first learn what fork() does before you use it.
Then you will understand why the line is executed twice.

In short: fork creates a copy of the current process and from then on both processes run the rest of the code. One major difference is that the return code from the child is 0 and from the parent the pid of the child.

Answer (score 2):

Fork returns a different PID to both of the processes. The parent process receives the PID of the child, and it returns 0 to the child process. So the reason you're seeing two prints is because both processes are printing the value that was returned to them.